# Optaplanner vehicle routing problem optimize to use best truck

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to solve the vehicle routing problem using Optaplanner. While the code works ok, I noticed something curious.

When I build the model I have a list of vehicles that have different characteristics. The vehicle fleet is heterogeneous and is composed of multiple vehicle types. Each vehicle type can have 1 or more vehicles. Vehicle category A could be a large truck while vehicle category B could be a small truck (and so on).

While I'm able to model correctly the vehicles in Optaplanner, when I actually run the solver I realised that the vehicles get allocated based on their position in the list. So if I place all vehicles A at the beginning, the solver will try to use them first, before using the vehicles B and vice-versa.

Here is the sample of the model that I use (very similar to what I found in [Github](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/main/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting)):

```java
@PlanningSolution
public class VehicleRoutingSolution {
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    protected List<Location> locationList;

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    protected List<Depot> depotList;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    protected List<Vehicle> vehicleList;

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider
    protected List<Customer> customerList;
    
    @PlanningScore
    protected HardSoftLongScore score;
}

@PlanningEntity
public class Vehicle {
    private int weight;
    private int volume;
    private float cost;

    @PlanningListVariable
    private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
}
...
```

My goal is not only to allocate orders inside the trucks without breaking their constraint (weight, volume), but more importantly make the solver decide which truck is best to use given the specific conditions and minimize the overall score (cost, distance, time), primarily because the routing distance changes as well based on the vehicle type.

Is there a way to model the domain so that I can make Optaplanner pick the best truck and not use them based on their position in the `PlanningEntityCollectionProperty` list?

Answer (score 0):

OptaPlanner (and [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/)) doesn't have any preference for assigning one truck or the other. *You do.* You see the solver doing something and you don't like it. This tells me you are missing some constraints.

They way how you specify your preference is by writing a constraint to penalize the unwanted behavior, or reward the preferred behavior. Every time you see a solution you don't like, think whether or not you've given the solver enough information to avoid that solution.

Comment: I have soft constraints that penalize distance and time and medium constraint that penalize the cost (as in dollar cost). I'm expecting the solver to use larger trucks because they can accommodate more orders thus reduce overall cost. But that happen only if I place them "at the beginning" of the list when I model the solution.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: I did quite a few tests, even removed all the constraint aside from the hard one (vehicle capacity etc) and got a medium constraint to minimize on the number of overall trucks. It still won't be able to allocate the right trucks despite being available, the only thing that worked is to order the trucks by capacity which brings a selection bias and perhaps is not really optimising well.